# How to check if user defined entry in vector in java?

Tags: java, vector, contains, comparable

I have a vector of entries. Each entry is an instance of this class:

```
public class Entry implements Comparable<Entry>{

    private String _key;
    private CustomSet _value;

    [...]

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Entry a) {
        return this._key.compareTo(a._key);
    }
}
```

The vector is declared as shown below:

```
Vector<Entry> entries = new Vector<Entry>();
```

After that, the vector is populated. Then I want to check if certain key is somewhere in the vector. So I do this:

```
Entry sample = new Entry(key, new CustomSet());
if (entries.contains(sample)) {
    // do something
}
```

This seems not to work. Why? How can I get it to work?

P.S.     CustomSet is another user defined class, irrelevant from my point of view

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to redefine the `equals` method in your `Entry` class, because that's what `contains` relies in to determine if an element belongs to a collection, as the docs say:

> Returns true if this vector contains the specified element. More
>   formally, returns true if and only if this vector contains at least
>   one element e such that (o==null ? e==null : o.equals(e)).

In this case `o` is `contain`'s method parameter.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you do not have the same object, but rather two different objects with the same Key.

This:

```
Entry sample = new Entry(key, new CustomSet());
```

makes a new object, and if you now call `entries.add(sample)` and then try to call `entries.contains(sample)` it will return true, since it is the same object, indeed. However, that would not be the case if you would have something like:

```
 Entry sample = new Entry(key, new CustomSet());
 Entry sample1 = new Entry(key, new CustomSet());

 entries.add(sample);

 if(entries.contains(sample1)) // It will still return false.
```

The solution involves the redefinition of the method `equals` using the `keys` to differenciate objects. So in the `Entry` class you should add the following:

```
 public boolean equals(Object o)
 {
       if(o == null || !getClass().equals(o.getClass()))  return false;
       if(o == this)  return true;
         
       Entry p = (Entry) o;
       return this.key.compareTo(p.key) == 0;
}
```